# Jquery: как переделать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть скрипт, который вызывается при клике по блоку и любым его дочерним элементам:

```js
$('.entry__item').click(function() {
  if(this.classList.contains('js--entry-selected')) {
    this.classList.remove('js--entry-selected');
  }
  else {
    this.classList.add('js--entry-selected');
  }
});
```

```css
 .entry__item{width:158px;padding:20px 13px 21px;margin-bottom:5px;margin-left:5px;display:inline-block;text-align:center;background:0 0;border:2px solid #a8a8a8}
 .entry__name{margin-bottom:5px;font-size:17px;font-weight:700;word-wrap:break-word}
 .entry__country{position:relative;display:block;margin-bottom:30px;font-size:14px;font-weight:300}
 .entry__country::after{content:"";position:absolute;bottom:-13px;left:50%;width:96px;height:1px;margin-left:-48px;display:block;background:#a8a8a8}
 .entry__btn, .entry__btn:focus{display:inline-block;padding:11px 20px;margin-bottom:12px;font-size:12px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;background:#a8a8a8;color:#fff;border-bottom:4px solid #757575;border-radius:3px; text-decoration: none;}
 .entry__btn:hover{background:#cc0001;border-color:#B40001; text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}
 .entry__btn:active{background:#B40001;border-color:#B40001; text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}
 .entry__info{font-size:16px;font-weight:300;color:#000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
 .js--entry-selected{background:#cc0001;color:#fff!important;border-color:#fff}
 .js--entry-selected .entry__country::after{background:#fff}
 .js--entry-selected .entry__info{color:#fff;border-color:#fff}
```

```html
<div class="entry__item">
  <span class="entry__name">НАЗВАНИЕ КОМПАНИИ</span>
  <span class="entry__country">Страна</span>
  <button class="entry__btn">Записаться на встречу</button>
  <a href="#id_company" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="entry__info">Информация о компании</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

А нужно, чтобы он срабатывал только по клику на `button`.

Казалось бы, всё просто - вешаю клик не на `.entry__item`, а на `.entry__btn` и вместо `this` пишу `$('.entry__item')`. Но почему-то так не работает.
Подскажите, как переписать правильно?

Comment: навешать событие на кнопку и смотреть `.closest('.entry__item')` - ближайшего предка?

Comment: @vp_arth, надо было ответом

Comment: @Grundy Too specific, польза этого вопроса весьма сомнительна

Comment: @vp_arth, почему? определять когда нужно вешать обработчик на контейнер, а когда на внутренний элемент, частая задача

Comment: @Grundy, уговорил) Оформил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A зачем вы мешаете `jquery` и `javascript`? Чтото одно уже б использовали.

```js
$('.entry__btn').click(function() {
  let parent = $(this).closest('.entry__item');
  parent.toggleClass('js--entry-selected');
});
```

```css
.entry__item {
  width: 158px;
  padding: 20px 13px 21px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 2px solid #a8a8a8
}

.entry__name {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

.entry__country {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300
}

.entry__country::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 96px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: -48px;
  display: block;
  background: #a8a8a8
}

.entry__btn,
.entry__btn:focus {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #a8a8a8;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #757575;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.entry__btn:hover {
  background: #cc0001;
  border-color: #B40001;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.entry__btn:active {
  background: #B40001;
  border-color: #B40001;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.entry__info {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.js--entry-selected {
  background: #cc0001;
  color: #fff!important;
  border-color: #fff
}

.js--entry-selected .entry__country::after {
  background: #fff
}

.js--entry-selected .entry__info {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="entry__item">
  <span class="entry__name">НАЗВАНИЕ КОМПАНИИ</span>
  <span class="entry__country">Страна</span>
  <button class="entry__btn">Записаться на встречу</button>
  <a href="#id_company" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="entry__info">Информация о компании</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том что вы пытались обратиться к методу classList с jQuery объекта, а у него этого метода нет, есть более простой вариант на jQuery в 1 строку:

```
$('.entry__btn').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.entry__item').toggleClass('js--entry-selected')
});
```

Comment: `this` внутри обработчика - это не jQuery объект, это дом элемент, к которому привязан обработчик и у него это свойство есть

Answer (score 3):

> нужно, чтобы он срабатывал только по клику на button.

Значит и нужно навешивать обработчик события клика на `button`.
Причём есть 2 принципиально разных способа сделать это:

1) Непосредственный обработчик на кнопке

```
$('.entry__btn').click(function() {
  // this === button
});
```

2) Делегированный обработчик [$.on(..., selector, ...)](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
В этом случае мы устанавливаем обработчик события на родителя, но он делегирует обработку потомку, в случае, если инициатором был потомок.

```
$('.entry__item').on('click', '.entry__btn', function() {
  // Здесь также this === button
});
```

Плюс второго подхода в том, что у нас всего один обработчик на все целевые элементы. К тому же, если подходящий элемент будет создан позже динамически - событие будет обработано и на нём.

#### Манипуляции с родителем

Можно получить ближайшего родителя в иерархии, соответсвующего некоторому селектору c помощью метода [$.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(this).closest('.entry__item').toggleClass('js--entry-selected');
```

---

```js
$('.child.ex1').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.parent.ex2').on('click', '.child', function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent').toggleClass('active');
});

// Добавим кнопки динамически
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.parent.ex1').append($('<div class="child ex2">Dynamic Button</div>'))
  $('.parent.ex2').append($('<div class="child ex2">Dynamic Button</div>'))
}, 2e3);
```

```css
.parent {display: inline-block;width: 30vw;margin: auto;border: 1px solid silver;position: relative;text-align:center;padding: 5px;}
.child {display: inline-block;border: 1px solid silver;cursor: pointer;margin: 5px;}
.parent.active,.child:hover {background-color: teal}
```

```html
<div class="parent ex1">
  <div class="child ex1">Example 1</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="parent ex2">
  <div class="child ex2">Example 2</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, вы используете избыточную конструкцию — вместо проверки на наличие класса и его дальнейшего добавления-удаления можно просто использовать `toggle`.

```js
// это:

document.querySelector('.first').onclick = function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
    this.classList.remove('selected');
  } else {
    this.classList.add('selected');
  }
}

// полностью идентично этому:

document.querySelector('.second').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('selected');
}
```

```css
button.selected {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class=first>click me</button>

<button class=second>click me</button>
```

Во-вторых, обратите внимание на разницу между `$(this)` и `this`, `$('.first')` и `document.querySelector('.first')`. В зависимости от того, над чем вы будете производить манипуляции — jquery-объектом или экземпляром Element — зависит то, как именно придется переключать класс родителя.

```js
!$(function() {
  $('.first').click(function() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected'); // сработает, потому что мы берем экземпляр объекта Element и обращаемся к его свойству
    $(this).classList.toggle('selected'); // не сработает, у jquery-объекта нет свойства classList
  });
  
  $('.second').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected'); // сработает, поскольку вместо this используется $(this) — jquery-обертка над this и метод jquery toggleClass
  });
  
  console.log( $('.first') ); // результатом будет jquery-объект со своими свойствами
  console.log( document.querySelector('.first') ); // результатом будет экземпляр объекта Element с базовыми свойствами и методами
  
  // собственно, переключение класса для внешнего блока
  
  $('.third').click(function() {
    this.closest('.outer').classList.toggle('selected'); // в формате vanilla js
  });
  
  $('.fourth').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.outer').toggleClass('selected'); // в формате jquery
  })
});
```

```css
button.selected {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.outer {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.outer.selected {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class=first>click me</button>

<button class=second>click me</button>


<div class=outer style="margin: 2em 0 .5em">
  <button class=third>click me</button>
</div>

<div class=outer>
  <button class=fourth>click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: как данный ответ связан с вопросом?

Comment: @Grundy немного увлекся описанием того почему не работает, что аж не дописал как сделать, чтобы работало. обновил ответ.